# private TreeMap with objects as values sent to another method to change the objects' properties

Tags: java, pass-by-reference, treemap, pass-by-value

My question is basically if this will work, and if not, why not?

```
public class main {
private TreeMap<Integer, obj1> obj1_tmap = new TreeMap<Integer, obj1>();
    for(int i = 0;i<100;i++){
        //create objects
        obj1 myObject = new obj1();

        // Set some properties of the object
        myObject.setProperty1("BlaBla");
        myObject.setProperty2("BlooBloo");
        obj1_tmap.put(i,myObject);
    }
    // Then send this TreeMap to another method
    method1(obj1_tmap);
    // Iterate over this TreeMap now and hopefully find 
    //that the underlying objects was changes in method1
}

public class method1(TreeMap<Integer, obj1> the_obj1_treemap) {
    // Iterate over this TreeMap to change some of the objects insides properties
    for (Entry<Integer, obj1> the_obj1 : the_obj1_treemap.entrySet()){
        // Change properties of each object here
        the_obj1.setProperty1("whatever");
        // set some new properties as well
        the_obj1.setProperty5("foobar");
     }
}
```

Does it matter that the TreeMap was originally declared as private. Will making it public change anything. Or does this not work no matter what. And you should send back a newly constructed TreeMap from method1?

Thank you in advance

Comment: nope, it doesn´t matter, as you pass the instance of the `TreeMap` to the method and not it´s acces modifier. Making it public wont change anything. If you want to send back a new map isn´t answerable as we don´t know if you want to modify the old data or if you want to create a modified list based on the passed map. Also you can´t programm out of methods, so both classes aren´t even close to be valid syntax. Before continuing with this, i´d suggest to start with a basic java tutorial, as these basic skills are not aviable judging the posted code (basicly allmost everything is wrong there).

Comment: Also, you can't make a variable private or public inside a method, that's only for class properties.

Comment: @RayO'Kalahjan uhm, that´s completly wrong and could suggest that java works with `pass-by-reference`

Comment: @KevinEsche what is completely wrong?

Comment: @RayO'Kalahjan `everything in Java is passed by reference, except the primitive types`, as basicly everything gets passed as value

Comment: @KevinEsche Yeah, sorry, you're right. I didn't express myself correctly, I'll delete that comment. The fact that Java works with references and passes them by value doesn't help clarification.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:** Access modifier of `TreeMap<Integer, obj1> obj1_tmap` does not matter. The methods of obj1_tmap can be accessed with both private and public.

Your method1 tries to set properties in the value object of the [Map.Entry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html). Also your method1 must be a static function of a class, method1 can't be the class.

As such the code of method1 should be corrected to

```
public class M1 {
    public static void method1(TreeMap<Integer, obj1> the_obj1_treemap) {
        // Iterate over this TreeMap to change some of the objects insides properties
        for (Entry<Integer, obj1> the_obj1 : the_obj1_treemap.entrySet()){
            // Change properties of each object here
            the_obj1.getValue().setProperty1("whatever");
            // set some new properties as well
            the_obj1.getValue().setProperty5("foobar");
         }
    }

}
```

Notice the `the_obj1.getValue().setProperty1("whatever");`. You need to do getValue to get your `obj1 myObject` that you put in the Map initially.

Now in your `class main` you call this as `M1.method1(obj1_tmap);`

**Now to answer your question:** you are passing the instance of the TreeMap (pass by reference) to the method1 and access modifier plays no role here. Making it public wont change anything.

Also please take a basic java tutorial. It seems you are coming from either ruby/scala/js background. This syntax won't work in java.